# RegEx Match Nested Parameters

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks like this

`![video](Title of the video)[URL of the video]`.

How can I get the title of the video and the URL of the video in one RegEx match without any other part of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign capturing groups and use `match_obj.groups()` to return them as a tuple.

```
# s is the input string
title, url = re.match(r"!\[.*\]\((.*)\)\[(.*)\]", s).groups()
```

For the sake of readability, I prefer writing it using `re.VERBOSE` over a one-liner:

```
patt = re.compile(r"""
    !
    \[ .* \]    # video
    \( (.*) \)  # group
    \[ (.*) \]  # url
    """, re.VERBOSE)

title, url = patt.match(s).groups()
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks